# How to remove rotation of non planar faces?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have this object, it is so far no thickness.

[image]

However there are some faces where I accidentally rotated the X and/or Y axis so now there are parts standing out on the side.

[image]

Is there a way to reset these rotations, so that the whole plane will be flat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Edit mode, Select all vertexes, Then press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>,  <kbd>0</kbd>  This combination scales vertexes to zero on Y axis, and will make faces completely flat in x-z plane

Comment: thank you so much! the axis i had to scale to 0 turned out to be z, but i guess that's because i got mixed up in my own description! 
worked perfectly in the end, though, thank you so much!